# Sending json object as json array to an API

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have an API that accepts data format as `[ { "record_id": "TestID3" } ]`. I am trying to send `record_id` field using the form below in my angular project:

html:

```
<input id="record_id" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="member.record_id" name="record_id" #record_id="ngModel" placeholder="Enter Record ID">
```

component.ts:

```
export class MembersAddComponent implements OnInit {
member: Array<Object> = [];

constructor(private service: DataService ) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

submit() {
  this.service.importRecord(this.member).subscribe(member => {
    this.member = member;
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

}

}
```

And my service.ts:

```
importRecord(data): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('token', this.token);
    formData.append('content', this.content);
    formData.append('format', this.format);
    formData.append('returnFormat', this.returnFormat);
    formData.append('type', this.type);

    formData.append('overwriteBehavior', this.overwriteBehavior);
    formData.append('forceAutoNumber', this.forceAutoNumber);
    formData.append('data', data);
    formData.append('returnContent', this.returnContent);


    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, formData).map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The error that I get is below:

> {"error":"The data being imported is not formatted correctly.  The JSON must be in an array, as in [{ ... }]."}

I also tried `member:any = {}`, `member:Object = {};` but I got the same error. I am thinking that I am unable to format my `member` object as requested format. But I couldn't make it as desired format.

Comment: Share the expected JSON body, which will help in building the JSON from angular for your API.

Comment: Also share how `this.member` structed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ { "record_id": "TestID3" } ]
```

That is an array, containing a single element, which is an object.

```
member: Array<Object> = [];
```

that defines an array with no element at all.

```
[(ngModel)]="member.record_id"
```

That will try to read and write the property `record_id` of `member`, which is an array. It will not magically add an element to the array and set its property.

So what you need is an object that will be populated by the form. And then you need to put that object into an array before to send the array to the API.

Start by defining an interface to describe your object:

```
interface Member {
  record_id: string;
}
```

Then use one as the model for your form:

```
member: Member = {
  record_id: '';
};
```

...

```
[(ngModel)]="member.record_id"
```

Then put that member into an array before sending it:

```
submit() {
  const data: Array<Member> = [this.member];
  this.service.importRecord(data)...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell if this is due to an incorrectly formatted response from the POST or the body of the POST.

Things you can do:

1. Check the network tab in Chrome to verify that the request is being sent, it's content is valid JSON (use an online validator)
2. Check your API backend to see if the data you're sending is being saved, if so the error is with the format of the JSON in your response.
3. Verify in Chrome that the response data in the network request is valid JSON.
4. If all of these are true, you may need to consider using headers such as {requestType: 'json'} as detailed in the Angular docs here: [Request/Response Headers](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers)
5. If these are not true, then you will need to change the model of the object you are sending to reflect the object which is expected.